# Python] combine two text files into one (line by line)

Tags: python

I'm new to python. What I'm trying to do is combing file 'a' and file 'b' into one file LINE by LINE.

For example,

`text file a = a ("\n") b("\n") c`

```
text file b = 1("\n")2("\n") 3
```

text file new will contain `a 1("\n") b 2("\n") c 3`

```
def main():
  f1 = open("aaa.txt")
  f2 = f1.readlines()
  g1 = open("bbb.txt")
  g2 = g1.readlines()
  h1 = f2+g2
  print(h1)
```

I'm so sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Points :**

- Open file using `with`. No need to close file.
- Use `zip` function to combine two list.

**Code without zip with comments inline:**

```
combine =[]

with open("x.txt") as xh:
  with open('y.txt') as yh:
    with open("z.txt","w") as zh:
      #Read first file
      xlines = xh.readlines()
      #Read second file
      ylines = yh.readlines()
      #Combine content of both lists
      #combine = list(zip(ylines,xlines))
      #Write to third file
      for i in range(len(xlines)):
        line = ylines[i].strip() + ' ' + xlines[i]
        zh.write(line)
```

**Content of x.txt:**

```
1
2
3
```

**Content of y.txt:**

```
a
b
c
```

**Content of z.txt:**

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

**Code with zip function:**

```
with open("x.txt") as xh:
  with open('y.txt') as yh:
    with open("z.txt","w") as zh:
      #Read first file
      xlines = xh.readlines()
      #Read second file
      ylines = yh.readlines()
      #Combine content of both lists  and Write to third file
      for line1, line2 in zip(ylines, xlines):
        zh.write("{} {}\n".format(line1.rstrip(), line2.rstrip()))
```

Comment: thank you. what if I want to make z.txt a 1 ("\n") b 2("\n") c 3("\n") ?

Comment: not a ("\n")1("\n")b("\n")2("\n")c("\n")3

Comment: Check the updated code

Comment: never knew "Opening file using with. No need to close file." thanks! it helped me so much

Comment: @DineshPundkar Good to see your edited code, range instead of combine. Nice catch.

Comment: @SivaShanmugam and user6886108 - Same thing can be achieve with zip function. Check the code.

Comment: No need to read the whole files into lists. As files are iterators, you can use `zip` directly on them: `for line1, line2 in zip(yh, xh)`

Answer (score 1):

Read more about file handling and using the in-built functions efficiently.
For your query just using `h1 = f2+g2` is not the way.

```
a=open('a.txt','r').readlines()
b=open('b.txt','r').readlines()
with open('z.txt','w') as out:
    for i in range(0,10): #this is for just denoting the lines to join.
         print>>out,a[i].rstrip(),b[i]
```

Comment: wow.. you made my day. I 've been working on this problem since yesterday. To write a new file on what you've made, what should I do instead of print(a[i].rstrip(),b[i]) ? I know I should start with newfile = open("new","w")

Comment: What if lines are more than 10?

Comment: @user6886108 @Dinesh Instead of 10 you can you use the len of file a or file b which has least number of lines. When you use which has more lines than the other one. This lines (`print a[i].rstrip(),b[i]`) will throws error.

Comment: @user6886108 Modified code to store in the separate file as `z.txt`.