# Python Merge two files together

Tags: python

File 1:

```
Hello
```

File 2:

```
Bye
```

What I want to output:

```
First: Hello | Last: Bye
```

My code:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file: 
            with open('First.txt') as f:
                with open('Second.txt') as f2:
                    output_file.write('First: ' + f.read() + ' | Last: ' + f2.read())
                    output_file.write('\n')
```

It outputs:

```
First: Hello
 | Last: Bye
```

I've been here for ages trying to get it working, but every other way I have tried outputs the same

Comment: `strip` the newline from the end of the line in the first file: ` ...  + f.read().strip() + ...`

Comment: What happens if the files have more than one line? Can you give a more general example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python\] combine two text files into one (line by line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717828/python-combine-two-text-files-into-one-line-by-line)

Answer (score 1):

Try ignoring end of lines using strip
then merge the files again
Example:

> f.read().rstrip('\n')

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re
firstFile = re.sub("\n", " ", open("path.txt").read())
secondFile = re.sub("\n", " ", open("path.txt").read())
print('First: ' + firstFile  + ' | Last: ' + secondFile)
```

Comment: It outputs First: Hello
Hi | Last: Bye

Comment: Here is my First.txt file; https://gyazo.com/05181bf1a1753548d572cef91e279d4d

Comment: Here is my Second.txt file: https://gyazo.com/b2f9d13b4f15e5e7cbcb0f255e36bab5

Comment: Here is what it otuputs: gyazo.com/dc3713136bdefcde17c7e3d2d1b87465

Comment: @KB856KDHI7RBE Where did the `hi` came from? Please provide a general [mre] in the question

Comment: I provided it .

Comment: then substitute new lines like this, it works for me `re.sub("\n", " ", file)` . Edited the same